# What to do to get Visa before my travelling date?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I am from India, New Delhi. I have applied for a UK visa for me and for my wife on the 29th of September 2015, with that application I had given a written application for processing our visa request on an urgent basis as I have my training schedule in my London office starting from 12th of October and our tickets are booked for the 11th of October (Sunday). The reason I couldn't apply for priority visa, as the counselor informed me that I am not eligible for that facility because I am travelling out of India for the first time. Can someone please suggest me what should I do to get my visa at the earliest. Now as I have three days left only!

Answer (score 3):

Visitor applications in New Delhi are processed at the BHC hub there and generally take 15 working days before a decision is reached; this is capped by a ceiling of 90 days.

In your case an application submitted on 29 September would be ready by 20 October, plus another day to be sent back to the Visa Application Centre, plus whatever delivery time is appropropriate.

Given that you do not qualify for the premium service, you would be very lucky indeed to get a decision and delivery by 11 October, but there are still 3 days left for it to happen.   Note that they advise applicants not to purchase flight tickets in advance of a decision.